# C++ Custom iterator for both const and non const container

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, constants, containers

I want to implement a custom tree type (stl like) and a custom iterator for the tree. As my understanding of the standard library is, any container have only 4 types of iterator (combinations of const/non const, reverse/non reverse) and const is referred to the data it holds, not to the container itself.

For some reason, in my iterator class I have attributes of type tree (and i need to return a const correct reference to it) and this forces me to have a different type when the user create a const container.

```
template <typename T> class tree;
template <typename T> class node;

template <typename T, typename Tree = tree<T>, typename Node = node<T>>
class iterator_base : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T> {
protected:
    Tree *tree;
    Node *current_node;
public:
    Tree& get_tree() const {
        return *tree;
    }
    //...
};
```

Is there a possibility to use the same iterator type for both `const tree` and `tree`?

Answer (score -1):

Basically you should be able to use the following version of your iterator:

```
typedef iterator_base<T, tree<T>, node<T> > iterator;
//either use T or const T for const_iterator (depends on your definition
//of const correctness in this case.
typedef iterator_base<T, const tree<T>, const node<T> > const_iterator;
```

The only thing missing is an implicit conversion from iterator to const_iterator (can either be done using a template_if or by subclassing and specifying only these members. If you use `const T` you may need additional helper functions to convert a `tree<T>` into a `const tree<const T>`)

Note: This approach only works if there are no special non-const members on the iterator which directly modify the tree/nodes (such methods would/should not work on a const_iterator)

Comment: Yes, but I have 2 different types for each of the 4 types of iterators, and this is want I want to avoid.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem correctly. If you're container uses a const tree, then you effectively have a different container than if you just use tree. Two different containers means that you effectively also have different iterators.